# Make field start at 1 and increment by 1 for every new field value in an MS-Access 2013 form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Update:**
I got it working. Here is the code I used to do this:

```
Private Sub Amount_GotFocus()

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[Line#]", "[t_Line#]", "[PO#] = [PO#].Value")) Then
    [CustPOLine#].Value = DMax("[CustPOLine#]", "t_CUST_PO_LineItems", "[CustPO#] = [CustPO#].Value") + 1
Else
    [CustPOLine#].Value = 1
End If

End Sub
```

I use DLookup to check if there are any values in the table with the same PO# as the one in the form's textbox. If it returns null, I set the value of Line# to 1. If it is not null, I use the DMax function to get the highest value for Line# where the PO# is equal to the one entered in the form.

Comment: Is the Cust PO ID an autonumber in the LineItems table?

Comment: @random_answer_guy yes it is, I edited my post near the bottom

Comment: You should probably change that to a Number / Long Integer, that way you can control the numbering. Trying to reset autonumbers is problematic

Comment: @random_answer_guy I am not resetting the Cust PO ID number back to 1, I am resetting CustPOLine# back to 1 (which isn't autogenerated). CustPOID is used for indexing only, nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Before Insert` event of your subform, assign the new number.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim CustPO As String  ' (!)
    Dim MaxLineNr As Long

    CustPO = Me.Parent![CustPO#]
    Debug.Print "CustPO# = " & CustPO   ' Ctrl+G shows output

    MaxLineNr = Nz(DMax("[CustPOLine#]", "t_CUST_LineItems", _
                        "[CustPO#] = '" & CustPO & "'"), 0)
    Debug.Print "MaxLineNr = " & MaxLineNr

    Me![CustPOLine#] = MaxLineNr + 1

End Sub
```

How does it work?

We want the maximum existing [CustPOLine#] for the current [CustPO#]. The latter is read from the main form (`Me.Parent`), because that field isn't filled yet in the subform (the new record doesn't exist yet) (I think).

If there is none, `DMax()` will return NULL, which is changed to 0 by `Nz()`.

Then 1 is added to the highest existing number.

Comment: I editted it to match my exact variable names (some of them got a little mixed up when I was making the 2 forms before). So I have [CustPOLine#] = Nz(DMax([CustPOLine#], "t_CUST_PO_LineItems", _
                               "[CustPO#] = " & Me.Parent![Cust PO#]), 0) + 1 but when I click and press any key on the "Amount" section, it gives me the error "3464: Data type mismatch in the criteria expression".

Comment: @Michael: Then let's split up the code, see edit. Is the error still there? What Debug output shows the Immediate window? `CustPO#` is a number (Long Integer) field, right?

Comment: Yes that same error is coming up again. It's on the line: "MaxLineNr = Nz(DMax("[CustPOLine#]", "t_CUST_PO_LineItems", "[CustPO#] = " & CustPO), 0)"  Also, the Sub "Form_BeforeInsert" is being called when I try to edit the Amount value, why is that? I thought it would be when I press tab or enter on the last field in the tab order?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that no CustPO# is not a number, it's a short text. I know it's a bit deceiving but that's the way the database was set up when I came here.

Comment: Meh. :) Then you need single quotes around the criterion, see edit.

Comment: Great no more errors! But it is not working properly :( The fact that it is jumping to the Form_BeforeInsert sub after I press a key on the Amount textbox is messing everything up. It does not update the next records line number. Should this method be called as the form is being 'submitted'? If so how can I change when it is called?

Comment: This mustn't be `Form_BeforeUpdate`, but `Form_BeforeInsert` !

Comment: I made a typo, I do actually have Form_BeforeInsert

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem. The sub runs only for new records when they are inserted. It doesn't affect other records (were you expecting that?) What is messed up?

Comment: That's what I thought would happen! After I 'exit' the last textbox in the form, it automatically inserts the new record. So when I leave the Job_Link_Code textbox, THEN the sub should be called. Correct me if I'm wrong? Because of this, when the sub is called, it is not even going to the next record..

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. I use this technique (setting dynamic default values in `BeforeInsert`) in a lot of forms, it works flawlessly. It doesn't disrupt the tab cycle or moving to a new record. If you can upload a copy of your database to a file hoster, I can take a look, but otherwise I'm afraid I'm out.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload it since it has sensitive information. Thanks for all your help your method did make sense, just have to figure out what's causing this problem

Answer (score 2):

With Access 2010 or later there is also the option of using a Before Change data macro to assign the line-item number. This approach only assigns the number when the row is actually committed, so it could be used in addition to Andre's form-based method to cover cases where rows are added by some other (non-form-based) mechanism such as batch updates, imports, etc..

[image: BeforeChange.png]